# Converting htaccess setting to BaseHTTPServer setting

Tags: python, .htaccess, iframe, basehttpserver

So what I'm trying to do is allow users to embed an image on their site, and then that image be automatically replaced by an iframe with their button inside.  The reason is to make it easy for users avoiding using js or other code on networks where they're not allowed.

This is possible in apache with PHP, but the way to do this in python is not particularly obvious to me.

original htaccess:
      `Redirect /embed.jpg http://somesite.com/embed.php`

But in python, it doesn't really work (this example doesn't work).

server.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import BaseHTTPServer
import getopt
import socket
import sys

ADDR = ["", 8080]

def usage(f = sys.stdout):
    print >> f, "Usage: %s [ADDRESS [PORT]]" % sys.argv[0]

class Handler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == "/":
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
            self.end_headers()
            print >> self.wfile, """\
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body bgcolor=dodgerblue>
<img src="x.png" width=200 height=200>
</body>
"""
            return
        if self.path == "/x.png":
            self.send_response(302)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "image/png")
            self.send_header("Location", "x.html")
            self.end_headers()
            return
        if self.path == "/x.html":
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
            self.end_headers()
            print >> self.wfile, """\
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body bgcolor=slateblue>
Inner HTML.
</body>
"""

        self.send_response(404)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
        self.end_headers()
        print >> self.wfile, """\
<!DOCTYPE html>
Not found.
"""

class Server(BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True

opts, args = getopt.gnu_getopt(sys.argv[1:], "h", ["help"])
for o, a in opts:
    if o == "-h" or o == "--help":
        usage()
        sys.exit(0)

if len(args) >= 1:
    ADDR[0] = args[0]
if len(args) >= 2:
    ADDR[1] = args[1]
if len(args) >= 3:
    usage(sys.stderr)
    os.exit(1)

server = Server(tuple(ADDR), Handler)
print "Listening on %s:%d." % (server.server_name, server.server_port)
server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: You're saying it doesn't work: what is happening exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Two problems I can see with that code...

First, the `<img src="x.png" width=200 height=200>` implies the browser should expect image data back, but instead you redirect them to another URL which returns HTML data.

Second, I think you're missing a `return` in the `if`-block directly before the line...

```
self.send_response(404)
```

I don't think it's possible to replace an `<img>` tag with an `<iframe>` tag without modifying the DOM in JavaScript.

Comment: Good point. I've also indicated content-type as being an image, which is wrong since I'm trying to serve up html.